# The two capacitors are in series but positive end of one plate is connected to positive end of the other

Tags: voltage, capacitor, energy, charge, equivalent-circuit

Like the title says, my task is to find the initial voltage across the terminals. The two capacitors are in **Series** with positive end of one plate connected to that of another.

The given information are:

\$C_1\$ = 12 **microFarad**, \$V_1\$ = 6 **Volts**, \$C_2\$ = 4 **microFarad**, \$C_2\$ = 2 **Volts**.

The circuit diagram is:

[image]

I have calculated the equivalent capacitance and I just need the total charge in the circuit to find the total or initial voltage using the equation,

**Q = C*V**

So, I first attempted to find \$Q_1\$ = \$C_1\$ * \$V_1\$ = 72 **microCoulomb**.

\$Q_2\$ = \$C_2\$ * \$V_2\$ = 8 **microCoulomb**.

I know that the positive charges accumulate on the positive end of the capacitor,

Hence, I am unsure whether \$Q_T\$ or Total Charge in the circuit = \$Q_1\$ + \$Q_2\$ or the difference between the two charges which is |\$Q_1\$ - \$Q_2\$|?

Comment: That top capacitor is very dead. The symbol says it's a polarized capacitor, but it's got 6 V on it in the reverse direction; I don't think it's going to remain a capacitor for very long.

Comment: It's an open circuit - no current is flowing and the charges on the capacitors have not equalized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *my task is to find the initial voltage across the terminals.*

You are overthinking this; it's quite simply 2 volts minus 6 volts or, 6 volts minus 2 volts if your reference node is at the top.